# Install Two same apk but using different WebService Url

Tags: android, android-build-flavors, build-variant

My Client is looking for two different android application on their phone one for testing purpose and one for the production. Testing application will be used by the client to show the demo's to different third level clients.
I am using **"com.xyz"** as a application id for my android application I want to build two different apk's but with the same application id this is because I have a project created on google console with say **"com.xyz"** for push notification. If I change the application id for another application then push notification won't be able to work. I have seen the process of using build variant for different flavors but have not tried yet. In lots of examples in different flavors I have seen that the application id's are different for the different flavor. If application id is different then will my application be able to get push notifications.

Comment: you can add multiple app packages in one `Firebase` project ....after thar get a final google-services.josn thus you can get push notifications with same server key and the googl-services.json will work for both or more than 2 packages at a time

Comment: So in the case If I received a notification and tap on notification which app gonna run ? can we configure this situation as well ?

Comment: obviously which app will receive the notification that will run on tap of notification

Comment: in some cases I've added 6 to 7 packages into single Fire-base project and I'm managing all of them individually ....

Comment: Sorry If I am not understanding. But lets say I have two apps in my same deivce and I if the notification is pushed from the server then how come know that the notification is for which application.

Comment: long tap on notification then you will get to know that this notification is shown by which package ..or app.... and that's depending on your `device token`

Comment: because token is generated different depending on package name not same for all packages in one device ...

Comment: Thanks its working ...

Comment: Can we create two different Onesignal project with same server api key and project no. For live and production?

Comment: I never tried Onesignal maybe there is any option for live or debug build or you can create your own logic in your code actually your question is of different type it's good if you edit your question properly what you want to ask.

Comment: So I could explain better answer